# What is a semantic event in Java?

Tags: java, terminology

I came across this term "semantic" from the Java API but couldn't get much information on what is it actually even after spending hours of research.

**Question:** So what is semantic in Java's perspective and what are semantic events?

This is the source where I came across this term: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionEvent.html

Answer (score 1):

A semantic event is an event that represents interaction with a GUI item.
For example, an `ActionEvent` is a semantic event fired when clicking a button, selecting a menu item, etc.

Comment: It seems to be, based on the usage of the term semantic in relation to the [list of events](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/package-summary.html) in the Abstract Window Toolkit.